# EnvCommandError when Poetry installing dependencies

Tags: 32-bit, python-poetry, virtualenv-commands

I'm having the following issue when trying to install the dependencies of my project with poetry:

ERROR: pywin32-301-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
ERROR: pyrsistent-0.18.0-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

my python version is 3.8 (64bit)

I don't know why is trying to install 32bit whl...
thanks!